# Jhbuild instruction for Newcomers

Tags: gnome, compiling, jhbuild

I was following Newcomers guide on GNOME's wiki. Everything was good up to running below command on guide

```
$ jhbuild build adwaita-icon-theme dconf glib-networking gvfs libcanberra
```

On terminal it gives following output (just error part):

```
Makefile:464: recipe for target 'dconf-dconf-update.o' failed
make[2]: *** [dconf-dconf-update.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mkykadir/.cache/jhbuild/build/dconf/bin'
Makefile:387: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mkykadir/.cache/jhbuild/build/dconf'
Makefile:327: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Error during phase build of dconf: ########## Error running make -j 3  *** [23/30]

  [1] Rerun phase build
  [2] Ignore error and continue to install
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Yapılandırmayı yeniden yükle
  [6] Go to phase "dizini temizle ve baştan başla"
  [7] Go to phase "configure"
  [8] Go to phase "clean"
  [9] Go to phase "distclean"
seçim:
```

Which operation to follow, I tried 1, 4 and 6 options and they didn't change the situation. I am using Ubuntu GNOME on a dual core machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem by detail looking the terminal outputs. In output, it gave an error about **dconf-update.c** which were some syntax errors. In my system, code file was in `~/jhbuild/checkout/dconf/bin` and errors were caused by

```
catch0_g_fıle_error
```

as you can see, (I think, not sure) Vala interpreter put **ı** which is not in ASCII character instead of **i**, I have searched for **fıle** in source code with my text editor and changed **ı**'s with **i**'s and selected option 1(*Rerun phase build*) and it worked.